# Azure Cosmos DB geospatial lookup consuming too high RU

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a single Azure Cosmos DB collection I am querying against, hoping to use Geo-spatial index for efficient queries.  The problem I'm encountering is that the RU consumption seems inefficient.

The collection has only 50k 1kb documents in it, but a query using ST_DISTANCE returning a single document consumes >900 RUs.

I've seen the RUs scale linearly based on the # of documents in the collection.  It would seem indexing should prevent this behavior.

Example Query (950 RUs):

```
SELECT * FROM c where ST_DISTANCE(c.location, { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [34.69, -1.91] }) < 500
```

Example document:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1504891036",
        "name": "Oujda",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                34.69,
                -1.91
            ]
        },
        "population": 409391,
        "country": "Morocco",
        "country.iso2": "MA",
        "country.iso3": "MAR",
    }
]
```

I've not modified the default indexing policy, which seems to cover spatial indexing:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Spatial",
                    "dataType": "Point"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Comment: What is your partition key?

Comment: No partition key, just a fixed 10gb single partition of which only 68MB is being used.

Comment: Are you on the emulator or the real thing?

Comment: behavior is the same on both.

Comment: FWIW, I think either the index hasn't been applied properly or the query isn't using it when it runs. I have replicated a dataset similar to yours. When I query using the index, my RU stays constant below 10. However, when I deliberately avoid the index I get ~1000RU.

Comment: How are you influencing whether your index is used or not?  I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: SELECT * FROM c WHERE ST_DISTANCE({'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[c.point.coordinates[0], c.point.coordinates[1]]}, {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[34.69, -1.91]}) < 500

Answer (score 1):

I determined the problem.  I had transposed the longitude and the latitude coordinate prescribed by GeoJSON:

Cosmos is expecting:

```
"location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                <@lon>,
                <@lat>
            ]
```

I had assumed, incorrectly, that it was lat/lon.  Therefore many of my latitudes were outside of the 90/-90 range required, since longitude can be 180/-180.  After re-creating my ~50k documents, RU for coordinate based lookups are consistently <10 RUs.

Before fix (all docs have transposed lat/lon coordinates, many outside the 90/-90 bounds and therefore invalid):

```
SELECT * FROM c where ST_DISTANCE(c.location, { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [34.69, -1.91] }) < 500
940 RUs, 1 document returned
```

After fix (all docs re-created with lat/lon set correctly per GeoJSON specs):

```
SELECT * FROM c where ST_DISTANCE(c.location, { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-1.91,34.69] }) < 500
6 RUs, 1 document returned
```

Initial issue was confirmed/diagnosed by the following query:

```
SELECT ST_ISVALIDDETAILED(c.location) FROM c where c.name = "Kansas City"
Error: "Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees."
```